# Create a ScheduleDefinition object in Powershell

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell, reporting-services, wsdl

I already have a powershell script that imports reports into SSRS with powershell using the ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl API.

I have issues with creating the cache options however, in particular to create a simple schedule.
The code example on the MSDN does not have a powershell example.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createcacherefreshplan.aspx

I was hoping someone could help me how to write this example in powershell?
In particular how to create a ScheduleDefinition object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the trick is to assign a namespace and class on your New-WebServiceProxy
I had this line in my code:

```
$RS = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerURI -UseDefaultCredential
```

Now I have changed it to this:

```
$RS = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $reportServerURI -UseDefaultCredential
```

This allows me to create the ScheduleDefinition object via

```
$definition New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinition
```