# Why Am I Seeing These Errors in My SSRS Powershell Script in One Environment but Not Another?

Tags: web-services, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reportservice2010

I have a Powershell Script I'm working on for post-migration SSRS report administration tasks.

In this particular scenario we have a DEV environment (where I've been primarily testing) which hosts a single instance of SSRS, and a Prod environment which is a scaled out deployment across 4 nodes.

I'm new to Powershell (just discovered it 2 days ago...) and the script I have is pretty simple:

```
Clear-Host 

$Username = "domain\myUsername"
$Password = "myPassword"

$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($Username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

# Dev Connection String
$webServiceUrl = 'http://DEVwebServer.domain.com/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?WSDL'

# Prod Connection String
# $webServiceUrl = 'http://PRODwebServerNode1.domain.com/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?WSDL'

$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $webServiceUrl -Credential $Cred
 
$reports = $rs.ListChildren("/Some Folder Under Root", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }

$type = $ssrsProxy.GetType().Namespace;
$schedDefType = "{0}.ScheduleDefinition" -f $type;
$schedDef = New-Object ($schedDefType) 

$warning = @();

foreach ($report in $reports) {

    $sched = $rs.GetExecutionOptions($report.Path, [ref]$schedDef);
    $snapShotExists = $rs.ListItemHistory($report.Path);


    if($sched -eq "Snapshot") {
        Write-Host "Following report is configured to run from Snapshot:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host ("Report Name: {0}`nReport Path: {1}`nExecution Type: {2}`n" -f $report.Name, $report.Path, $sched)

        if ($snapShotExists) {
            Write-Host "Does Snapshot Exist..?`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host "Yes!`tNumber of Snapshots: " $snapShotExists.Count -ForegroundColor Green
            $snapShotExists.CreationDate
            Write-Host "`n------------------------------------------------------------"
        } 
        elseif (!$snapShotExists) {
            Write-Host "Does Snapshot Exist..?`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host ("No!`n") -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "Creating Snapshot.......`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $rs.CreateItemHistorySnapshot($report.Path, [ref]$warning);
            Write-Host "Snapshot Created!`n" -ForegroundColor Green
            $snapShotExists.CreationDate
            Write-Host "`n------------------------------------------------------------"
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the script is simply to recursively iterate over all of the reports for the given folder in the $reports variable, check to see if the execution type is set to "Snapshot", if it is check to see if a "History Snapshot" exists, and if one does not exist, create one.

When I run this in Dev it works just fine, but when I run in PROD I get the following error repeated for each $report in my foreach loop:

[image]

Any ideas on why this would work in one and not the other and how to overcome this error?

Comment: Start by checking to see if the PS versions on the 2 machines are different (using `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` from a PS prompt). You may need to get the 2 machines on the same version is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working on the Prod instance by making some adjustments using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889225/create-a-scheduledefinition-object-in-powershell?rq=1) as a guide:

By updating my call to New-WebServiceProxy to add a Class and Namespace flag, I was able to update the script in the following ways:

```
...
# Add Class and Namespace flags to New-WebServiceProxy call
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $webServiceUrl -Credential $Cred
 
$reports = $rs.ListChildren("/Business and Technology Solutions", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }

# Declare new "ScheduleDefintion object using the Class declared in the New-WebServiceProxy call
$schedDef = New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinition
$warning = @();

foreach ($report in $reports) {

    # Referencing the "Item" property from the ScheduleDefinition
    $execType = $rs.GetExecutionOptions($report.Path, [ref]$schedDef.Item)

...
```

I don't think the adding of the Class and Namespace flags on the New-WebServiceProxy call was exactly what did it, as I think it's just a cleaner way to ensure you're getting the proper Namespace from the WebService. Maybe just a little sugar.

I think the key change was making sure to the "Item" property from the schedule definition object, although I'm not sure why it was working in Dev without doing so...